# Site Mailbox - System.NullReferenceException

Tags: 2013, site-mailboxes

I have set up site mailboxes on my farm, with no errors on the scripts.

Adding the site mailbox app onto a site yields the following error:

> Could not contact the SharePoint Server

The ULS log has the following information in it:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.CollaborationMailboxInternalService.ExchangeHasPermissionsToSiteSubscriptionInternal(SPWeb web, CollaborationMailboxErrorCodes& errorCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.CollaborationMailboxInternalService.<>c__DisplayClassf.b__e() StackTrace:  at Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll: (sig=678c0f87-966f-4d99-9c94-b49e788d2672|2|microsoft.office.server.native.pdb, offset=131CE) at Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll: (offset=21BE5)

I've tried redoing all the set up steps, have installed the latest exchange web services api...I don't know what else to do to fix this.

Any help on figuring out why this is happening would be very appreciated!

Comment: check this post, at the end, talking about the STS...https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cc9d4284-07fc-42c3-aede-1730bfc563ad/site-mailbox-error-code-0?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: Thanks @WaqasSarwarMCSE, It might actually be that, I'm looking into it now

Comment: Hi @WaqasSarwarMCSE, the error remains after the entire sharepoint farm was reverted to its original certificate. I checked the trustedIssuers, and there are two that do not have NameId's... Must all Issuers have NameIDs for Site Mailboxes to work?

Comment: are you using all ?

Comment: Yes, the other issuers are being used by other features, so removing them is not a viable option

Answer (score 2):

Please see this link to solve the certificate issue: http://www.oneplacesolutions.com/support/0109.html

Section IV and V

Creating the Server Certificate and Importing the Certificates

Comment: Hi Chad, We are using domain issued certificates, so the certificates should be fine...thanks very much for the article though, it covers the pre-requisites very nicely!